# Random Markov Field, Mean-Field inference and potential functions... perplexities

Tags: probability, probability-theory, graph-theory, random-graphs

I'd need help in understanding some concepts presented on a paper that I've started to read recently.

The general setting is about seeing graph structures from a probabilistic persepctive, in particular:

Let $\mathcal{G} = (V,\mathcal{E})$ be a graph with a multi-variate random variable $\textbf{X}_i$ associated to each node $i \in V$, and our goal is trying to infer some latent variables $\textbf{Z}_i$ given the initial observed variables $\textbf{X}_i$. The graph is said to be defining a **Markov Random Field**, writing

\begin{equation}
p(\{\textbf{z}_i\}, \{\textbf{x}_i\}) \propto \prod_{i \in V}\Phi(\textbf{x}_i,\textbf{z}_i)\prod_{(i,j) \in \mathcal{E}}\Psi(\textbf{z}_i,\textbf{z}_j)
\end{equation}

where I have used the shorthand $\{\textbf{x}_i\}$ for $\{\textbf{x}_i \, , \forall i \in V\}$, and $\Phi,\,\Psi$ are so-called non-negative *Potential Functions*.

It is also stated that $\Phi(\textbf{x}_i, \textbf{z}_i)$ works as the 'likelihood' of a node feature vector $\textbf{x}_i$ given its latent representation $\textbf{z}_i$, while $\Psi$ *controls the dependency between connected nodes*.

I just wanted to ask if any one could explain me a little better the roles of these functions $\Phi, \Psi$, why the first would act as a *likelihood* function, and also the overall perspective lying at the bottom of the above equation that gives a factorization of the joint distribution.

Thanks!

James

Answer (score 2):

Informally, there are two sources of information for $z$, the measurements $x$ and the "opinions" of the neighbors. Given the true value of $z$ we may have a model of the probability to see a measurement $x$. This model can be also interpreted in the other direction: *given* a measurement $x$, what can be said about the true value $z$. This is called the likelihood to stress that it is not a probability. The $\Phi$ function weights $z$ given $x$, so it acts like a likelihood.